# Providing Dummy-Annotation for older Java compilers

Tags: java, annotations

I'm working on a Java library that I would like to be able to use across a couple of different Java compiler versions. Some annotations (specifically [`@SafeVarargs`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SafeVarargs.html)) only exist on some of these compiler versions and generate errors in others.

Especially for something like `@SafeVarargs`, which serves mostly as a marker to suppress warnings rather than actually changing the output of the compiler, I would like to be able to use these annotations and simply provide a dummy-implementation if an earlier compiler is missing them.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could just create surrogate implementations of those annotations and put them in a Jar that is added to the classpath making sure that the system/compiler provided one take priority when resolved by the corresponding class loader.

For example you can just copy the code of SafeVarargs from [here](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/17990501/)

Comment: I guess I could add the jar file dynamically to the classpath only if needed, but I've actually always wondered about how to specify priority when it comes to resolving implementations, especially when dealing with the system library, which is not explicitly mentioned in the classpath. Do you know how I would do that?

Comment: Shallow googling seems to indicate that you cannot override system @MarkusA. classes (unless you play with the bootstrap classpath) and so your classes won't override them if present that is what you want. Don't see you should bother to make it dynamic as you always would need to have and compile the code of those annotations based on the weakest compiler and they don't take much space (the code is minimal).

Comment: Wow... I almost feel stupid for even asking this question... :) I guess sometimes the most obvious thing does the trick just fine! :) I just added a folder /java/lang in my project and in there created a file SafeVarargs.java that simply contains `package java.lang; public @interface SafeVarargs{}`. Done. Now everything compiles fine with Java 5, 6, and 7 (and probably others). Thanks! +1, √